# Convert LinkedIn page into showcase page

Tags: linkedin

I see that LinkedIn now offers showcase pages so you don't need to have a company page for a product. My company page is Wine With Spirit and I created a company page for one of our products at Lyfetaste.

Do you know if it's possible to turn that company page into a showcase page?

And if not, would deleting it free the name for me to re-create it as a showcase page?

I don't want to delete it and have it forever stuck.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no direct way to convert a company page into Showcase page. Deleting would not be free it name, and also you will lose your followers.

Better to create a new relative Showcase page and invite all company page followers to follow Showcase page.

I would suggest do not delete your company page. Deleting would not be a good idea. Might be you need this page in future.

Answer (score 0):

A showcase page is a sub page of a Company page. You need to have a company page. A good example is how [My company page](https://www.linkedin.com/company/2790267?) and corresponding [showcase sub pages](https://www.linkedin.com/company/best-linkedin-profiles-examples?trk=biz-brand-tree-co-name) are designed.